# How can I get a modal backdrop over a modal that's in the background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I'm opening a modal within a modal. So when the inner modal opens, I want its backdrop to cover the modal that it sits within. I hope this makes sense. Here's my simplified code structure:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="outer-modal">
 <a class="btn" href="#outer-modal" data-toggle="modal">Open Inner Modal</a>
</div>

<div class="modal hide" id="inner-modal">
 Some content here...
</div>
```

The reason I put the inner modal OUTSIDE of the outer modal is so that I can properly close only the inner modal without closing both.